# My redirect is not working (Ruby SInatra/REST routes)

Tags: ruby, sinatra-activerecord

I am having a route issue with my Sinatra application. I am using ActiveRecords btw. When I enter information on a form I have it set up to the target post method but the redirect is not working when it hits that post method. Instead it keeps looping back to the form I was just on.

```
get '/players/new' do 
        if logged_in?
            erb :'players/add_player'
        else
         redirect '/login'
        end
    end
```

Here is the ERB file that it renders

```
<h2>Add a member to the team</h2>
<form method ='/players' method='POST'>
<label for = 'name'>Name:</label>
<input type = 'text' name = 'name'id = 'name'><br>
<label for = 'position'>Position:</label>
<input type = 'text' name = 'position' id = 'position'><br>
<label for = 'height'>Height:</label>
<input type = 'text' name = 'name' id = 'name'><br>
<label for = 'weight'>Weight:</label>
<input type = 'text' name = 'weight' id = 'weight'><br>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Join The Team'>
</form>
```

And here is the post method it supposed to send information to

```
post "/players" do 
       if params == ""
         redirect to '/players/new'
       else
        @player = Player.create(params)
        redirect to "/players/#{@player.id}"

       end
    end
```

But keeps looping back to add_player file. Where am I going wrong.

Here is the get request its supposed to redirect to

```
get "/players/:id" do
        @player = Player.find(params[:id])
        erb :"players/show_player"
    end
```

Comment: To what form do you get redirected exactly, POST /players or POST /login? Is it possible that the login route is not setting any sessions correctly, thus redirecting forever?

Comment: I'll edit the question with the get request is supposed to redirect to

Comment: I used tux to try to input some data, and that worked and saved if that makes any sense to you

Comment: It loops back to the first get request @cesartalves

Answer (score 0):

My cohort lead  just looked at it, and it's one little syntax error. I fixed it and it worked. I forgot to change `method ='/players' to action = '/players'` at the top of my form. It was a little tricky to cathc in all the running around.